# Android Menu Text Stops Updating

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

We have a Xamarin Android app, with a navigation drawer.

Based on actions in the app, ... changing user name, changing mode, scanning items, we update some the text of various menu items in the navigation drawer to reflect the current state of the application and data, for easy viewing by the user.

The menu texts are updated with code along these lines... just with different actual IDs and text based upon the scenario.

```
private void BindThatMenuText() {
    IMenuItem menu = navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_someitem);
    menu.SetTitle($"Some Text ({State Indicator})");
}
```

It works perfect. You click things, or scan things, and the menu items update their text appropriately. It's all peaches.

But then after a while (could be 30mins, or an hour, or a day), the menus just stop reflecting the new text. ... It doesn't throw any errors, like if `navigationView` were null or anything. The code runs fine, but the menus just don't actually update anymore.

I've found two ways to make it start working again...

1. Reinstall the application
2. Under `App Info` delete the app's data

Doing either of those will make the menus start reflecting text-updates again as they are supposed to, until they stop again. Of course, we can't very well tell the user to just keep going and doing that.

Any ideas why the text updates would work for a while, and then just stop working, ... and start again if the app's data is cleared?

Comment: You may call validateoptionsmenu() to get this method again. And you may set a global variable in the activity to update your project later. Then, after executing an asynchronous task, thread, or any operation that updates the noofmsgs value, call this method.

Comment: Nope. No joy. Still doesn't update the text after it's stopped working. 

Comment: If the above description is correct - you need to delete app data to work, restart doesn't help, then it is a problem in application logic. Obviously without posting the code the question is not answerable.

Comment: So, I have no idea why this started stopping working. But ultimately, what we did was put some textviews on the main form layout, and update those instead of the text in the navigation-drawer menus, ... and that's had no issues. Literally no other code changes than finding the textview instead of the menuitem. Working fine. ‍♂️